# A non-changeable VMWare image

Tags: vmware, virtual-machine

I know the title is a bit weird, but I was unable to think a better one.

I wasunsuccessful in looking (googling) for creating a non-changeable VMWare image. I am not sure if this is even possible or not? Well the idea is that after VMWare restart I always have the same state.

Does anyone have any idea? Thanx in advance and hope it was not a completely stupid question.

Comment: Hi Gico, so what your saying is that if you power up the VM and its in state 1, make a change, like install some software maybe, then shutdown and power back up, your VM will be in state 1 again, ie the software wont be installed? Also are you using vSphere?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what i want. I would be happy if I may use VMWare Player. This should be more as a tool for our sales person.

Comment: The issue you are trying to address is interesting, you would imagine a solution to facilitate this exists. I'll keep having a look.

Comment: OK You can definetly set up a VM to 'Revert at power off' in VM ware player but I cant find a tutorial showing you how to do it, I dont have/use vmware player myself but if you have a dig around this is definetly the solution to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean that when you power off your VM you want it to revert back to a known state and lose the latest changes, then this is possible with VMWare Workstation and I suspect other versions too.

You need to get the VM to the state you want to roll back too, shut it down and take a snapshot of this state.

You can now change the snapshot settings of the VM (VM->Settings->Options->Snapshots I think, but I'm not in front of VMWare at the moment, so may be wrong). Now you can set the VM to "When Powering Off: Revert To Snapshot". Now, every time the VM is powered down, it should revert to your known "baseline".

Comment: Hi. Thanx for the answer. Yes this by VMWare's Snapshot Manager. I know that one. The problem is, that I am planing to give this virtual machine to our sales guys, and it would be really nice if they could always start from the same state without restoring the image. But apparently it wont be so easy as i thought.

Comment: Convert the virtual machine to a template, they can deploy off that then. I dont think there will be a way to do this without having to revert a snapshot though.

Comment: Hi Gico, can you take a look at the edit to my answer above and see if it is possible for you to do something like this in your environment.

Comment: @Gico - sorry - I wasn't that clear (minor edit to make the answer clearer). If you set this option above, it should automatically revert every time it is powered down. Your sales guys won't need to do anything themselves once this option has been set (as opposed to the manual "revert to snapshot" option, in which they would)

Comment: WOW! That was it! Great. Thank you Rob.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of you being able to do this Gico is that if you have a snapshot of the VM in whatever state you want, then revert to that snapshot whenever you need to, after a power down. This is definetly possible if you are using vSphere, not sure about the rest of VMware's products.

To do this in vSphere, get the machine in to the state you want, right click the VM in the vSphere Management console/ vCenter, select 'Snapshot -> Take Snapshot'. Then in the same snapshot menu use 'Snapshot Manager' to revert to that snapshot whenever you need to.

Maybe a way of reverting the snapshot automatically is described at this link:

http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_preserve_sshot_revert_or_goto.html

Look in the **Reverting at Power Off** section.

It is possible to use 'Revert at power off' in VMware player too.